# Yarn job failed with ClassNotFound exception but jar was added in HADOOP_CLASSPATH

Tags: hadoop, curl, hive, hadoop-yarn

I have a some issue with Hive WebHcat and Yarn.
When I trying to create table in hive via curl, like:

> curl -s -d execute="select+*+from+pokes;" \    -d
>   statusdir="pokes.output" \
>   'http://localhost:50111/templeton/v1/hive?user.name=ekoifman'

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/WebHCat+Reference+Hive

And Yarn container failed with

> Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.LoggerContextFactory

But needed jar exist in Hive class path, and when I launched WebHcat, I explicitly add log4j-api-2.4.1.jar in Hadoop classpath in https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/hcatalog/webhcat/svr/src/main/bin/webhcat_server.sh#L211-L215

So the question is why yarn container cannot found jar which landed in hive class path and explicitly added in hadoop_classpath?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved after I added log4j library which already present in hive classpath into yarn classpath.